# Selecting multiple elements with querySelectorAll and applying event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

there is an onchange event on the input and want it to change the value of the spans with the class of "number" whenever it changes so there here is the HTML :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value
  document.querySelectorAll(".number").innerText = x
}
```

```html
<div class="uper-container">
  <p>Metric/Imperial unit conversion</p>
  <!-- *********************************************************************************************** -->
  <!-- this input will change the value of 6's span below with the class of "number" -->
  <!-- ********************************************************************************************** -->
  <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="number here" value="20" onchange="myFunction()">
</div>
<div class="lower-container">
  <p>Length(Meter/Feet)</p>
  <p>
    <span class="number"></span> meters = <span class="d"></span>feet |
    <span class="number"></span> feet = <span class="d"></span>meters
  </p>
  <p>Volume(Liters/Gallons)
    <</p>
      <p>
        <span class="number"></span> liter = <span class="d"></span>gallon |
        <span class="number"></span> gallon = <span class="d"></span>liter
      </p>
      <p>Mass(Kilograms/Pounds)</p>
      <p>
        <span class="number"></span> kilogram = <span class="d"></span>pound |
        <span class="number"></span> pound = <span class="d"></span>kilogram
      </p>
</div>
```

so how to make spans with the class="number" have the same value as input id="myText"?
and one thing to mention is that I use scrimba editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike jQuery, Vanilla JS will not execute `innerText` to every node returned by `querySelectorAll` with an inline call. You would need to loop through them.

The code below should work:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
    for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].innerText = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: what this so strange  okay I will try it

Comment: is there any article about this? your answer is right btw  going to accept it

Comment: It isn't really that strange as `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList. jQuery adds convenience methods.

Comment: then what's the point of using querySelectorAll? it works kinda like querySelector then

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll. From the docs: "Once the NodeList of matching elements is returned, you can examine it just like any array. If the array is empty (that is, its length property is 0), then no matches were found. Otherwise, you can use standard array notation to access the contents of the list. You can use any common looping statement"

Comment: `querySelector` will only return the first match. It returns a single Node.

Comment: aha got it so with **querySelectorAll** you will provide information about all of them and then with loop  you will change all of them

Comment: I wouldn't say "provide information". `querySelectorAll` only fetches the nodes and returns them in a NodeList. By checking its `length` you'll know how many nodes were found. You can then execute operations to one, several or all of them, based on what you need to do.

Comment: It's been fashionable for years to hate on jQuery, but it really is convenient. (Not saying you're a hater of course.)

Comment: I'm kinda new , know nothing about jQuery

Comment: @Pointy I don't hate jQuery at all, and agree that it's extremely useful, although I wouldn't use it for simple websites. It's just OP didn't seem to use it, so I gave him the "pure JS" answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the for-of loop.

```
function myFunction() {
    const x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    const numberElements = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

    for (let element of numberElements) {
        element.innerText = x;
    }
}
```